# Odoo 12 to Odoo 14 migration - account.invoice and tax

Tags: migration, odoo

I am migrating from using Odoo 12 to Odoo 14. It seems like the **account.inovice** is removed and instead **account.move** can be used.
However, *account.move* does not have *acount_id*, tax_line_ids.

Do you know if *account_id* and *tax_line_ids* from *account.invoice* is replaced with something else?

Also, the model **account.invoice.tax** is removed. I read **account.move.line** is created instead.
But *account.invoice.tax* had few fields that seem missing from *account.move.line* like :

1. **invoice_id** - is it replaced with move_id?
2. **tax_id** - now, I see there is a tax_ids (multiple ids), how will that map?
3. **amount_total** - ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The  `account_id` was removed and they did not mention any mapping

The `account.invoice.tax` model was removed. Instead, now use `account.move.line` with the following mapping:

**field (account.invoice.tax)**  **field (account.move.line)**
 invoice_id          move_id
 account_analytic_id        analytic_account_id
 amount                price_unit
 base              tax_base_amount

`tax lines` subset of all `account.move.line` from a journal entry can be accessed by using the relational field `tax_line_id`

You can find a detailed description in the [accounting-pocalypse](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/beaa30a3d1843de43a45f419bfbc1bfa7613a920) commit